# What are some well-written open source Clojure applications (not libraries)?

Tags: clojure

I'd like to look at some examples of well-architected, complete Clojure applications (not libraries, but completed applications that accomplish real-world tasks for end users rather than for other developers.) Are there any such open source projects out there that are recommendable as examples of how to structure and write a user-facing application in Clojure?

Edit: I'd like to see a substantial full-blown application of some complexity as opposed to a prototype or a demo. Is there anything like that out there yet?

Comment: I'm not aware of any full-blown open sourced end-user application made in Clojure. There's more and more open source libraries and there's some commercial applications out there, but it will certainly take more time before we see an application like what you're asking for. Maybe this question could be made a Community Wiki for future use.

Answer (score 7):

[Lau Jensen](http://bestinclass.dk) has some [idiomatic clojure source for a DB-backed reddit clone on github](https://github.com/LauJensen/SocialSite), which makes for interesting reading. [Here's the corresponding blog post](http://bestinclass.dk/index.clj/2011/01/building-a-social-media-site.html).

Comment: This is very cool, and it's extremely impressive that it can be done so concisely, but it seems to be a prototype or proof of concept rather than a full-blown app. I'm looking for something more along the lines of a finalized, polished, end-user-ready application..

Comment: I understand, and the link I posted was the closest I've seen to what you wanted. Sadly, it seems too early in Clojure's uptake cycle to find substantial apps with publicly-shared source code. If Rails is anything to go by, it'll be a while before such codebases appear, even though there are already some substantial closed-source Clojure apps.